# How do I prep a, temporary, root login before editing sudoers?

Tags: mojave, startup, login, sudo

I want to alter my sudo capabilities on my mac, to avoid password prompts on starting postgres among other things.  I'm reading *Michael Lucas' Sudo Mastery* and generally have an OK idea on how to modify the entries and use **visudo**.

However, Michael makes the point that, regardless of what you do, editing **sudoers** is inherently unsafe and can lock you out of your machine.  And he goes out of his way to warn people to activate a root login, especially on macOS.  Once your **sudoers** file is ok and you've confirmed that with a reboot, you can always disable the root.

I mean, if it's just copying the original **sudoers** and then, when things blow up, safe boot, go to the Terminal and restore the backed up **sudoers**, that's fine.  But I want to be 110% sure I will not get locked out.

Note:  I might very well try my hand on a Linux VM's sudoers first, but I still want to have an escape route.

On macOS Mojave, keeping in mind Apple's various intentional security limitations around safe boots and SIP, what are the simplest steps to go create temporary root login *backdoor*?

Comment: This is the most awesome setup for a YAGNI answer ever. Welcome to macOS with APFS snapshots, recovery and internet recovery.

Comment: I’m confident you’ll get it all in time. Amazing answers here already, no rush to delve any deeper than you want. It’s a shame only one other person gave it a +1 so far. Great question.

Comment: ok, well, txs @bmike.  tell you the truth, I originally thought your comment was intended to be snarky, but I guess I misread your meaning .  This forum seems to be well split between regular everyday users of macOS and some terminal/Unix type users, but sudoers is probably rather obscure to people who are not sysadmins, so I expect it will remain a rather unnoticed question.

Comment: You hit the sweet spot - there is a pocket of people that will love answering your question - super warm welcome. I might even add a total non-answer explaining you don't need root to do anything you ask, but hit me up in [chat] if you're curious about that avenue - let's leave the answers you have for now... I was earnest in saying awesome.

Comment: Please don‘t include the solution into the question, post it as an answer below instead!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No backdoor is required, in fact really nothing (not even a backup) is required to edit the *sudoers* file. You can't get locked out of your machine.

A backup (`sudo cp /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.bak`) is more convenient though, because you can simply restore it with a one-liner.

Reasons:

1. *sudoers* is not required to authenticate a user at log-in
2. *sudoers* is not required to activate the root user with *Directory Utility* - only a working admin account. Authentication is done with the local OD services.
3. If you have a working Internet connection or a working local Recovery Mode (aka recovery partition) you can always restore the default *sudoers* file either from an online resource (e.g. pastebin or github) or as mentioned earlier: more convenient from a local backup file.
4. If you have a second Mac and some fitting cable you can always start the "broken" Mac in Target Disk Mode and transfer a working good *sudoers* file from the second Mac.

---

Tested in a Mojave VM by:

1. simply removing the sudoers file completely
2. editing *sudoers* with `nano` and commenting out the *root* and *%admin* line, changing ownership of *sudoers* to 501:staff and make it 777

Proof:

[image]

Comment: and all this activity to enable the root login was carried out **after** you nuked your *sudoers*, correct?   I tested the root user login, but, obviously, without screwing up my own sudoers first.  I guess I am asking for confirmation that I don't need to use Directory Utility to set up the root login *in advance*, I can do it *after* messing up sudoers, correct?  Yes, it sounds like you said just that, but still being cautious that I am not misinterpreting the sequence of events in your test.

Comment: @JLPeyret Exactly, you can enable root after screwing/deleting your sudoers file - even after a reboot, shutdown etc. 1. (`rm sudoers`) was one scenario 2. (`nano/chmod/chown sudoers`) was another scenario.

Comment: excellent.  you and @Gordon Davidson were both great.  you get it for the screenshot and, esp, the test.  txs.

Answer (score 3):

With due respect to the other folks who have offered suggestions so far, they are offering far more complicated ideas than are necessary.

Here is the simple truth: from *at least* 10.11 onward, there is no need to ever touch your `/etc/sudoers` file. None. Just leave it alone.

Look at the bottom of the `/etc/sudoers` file and you will see these lines:

```
## Read drop-in files from /private/etc/sudoers.d
## (the '#' here does not indicate a comment)
#includedir /private/etc/sudoers.d
```

What that means is that you can put files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` and `sudo` will read them *as if they were in the main `sudoers` file* without ever having to touch the official `sudoers` file.

(In some versions of macOS, you may need to create the folder via `sudo mkdir /etc/sudoers.d/` but in recent versions, it already exists.)

You can create/edit the file like this:

`sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/foo`

When you exit the editor, `visudo` will check the syntax for you, but even if you ignore the warnings and save it anyway, `sudo` will ignore any file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` which does not have the correct syntax, but your main `sudoers` file will remain intact and working.

You can run `sudo visudo -c` to check the syntax of any/all `sudoers` files, and to show that they are being read/included.

Files in `/etc/sudoers.d/` should be owned by root, they should be `chmod 440` and they should not have any file extension (i.e. “foo” is ok but not “foo.txt”) If you create the file using `visudo` it will automatically be given the correct permissions.

(Oh, and you don’t need to enable `root` on a Mac. I’ve used one since 2003 and done all sorts of weird stuff but I’ve never needed it.)

---

If you ever do manage to screw up your `/etc/sudoers` file, you can use [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) to edit the file. It will prompt you for your admin password, but once entered, it can edit the file and remove the offending line. But you should still never edit the `/etc/sudoers` file.

Comment: you know, come to think of it, there is probably also the advantage that future Apple-delivered changes to **/etc/sudoers** itself will not clobber your sudo-related adjustments.

Answer (score 2):

macOS is a bit safer than most unixish OSes in this respect, since it has paths to root that don't depend on `sudo`. If you do mess up /etc/sudoers, there are several ways to recover (even without advance preparation, aside from backing up /etc/sudoers):

- Run the Directory Utility (it's hidden in /System/Library/CoreServices/Applications, but Spotlight can find it). Click the padlock and authenticate, then choose Edit menu > Enable Root User, and enter a root password. When you're done with root, you can disable it the same way.
- You can use AppleScript's `do shell script ... with administrator privileges` to run shell commands as root. Open /Applications/Utilities/Script Editor, and enter something like this:

  ```
  do shell script "cp /etc/sudoers.bkp /etc/sudoers" with administrator privileges
  ```

  ... and press the run (right-pointing-triangle) button in the toolbar. Authenticate when prompted.

Then there's also the simple & universal method: before messing with /etc/sudoers, run `sudo -s` to open a root shell *and leave it open* so you can use it to recover if necessary. It obviously won't survive a reboot, but you can do basic tests on your new /etc/sudoers before rebooting.